# yamlbeans: why is a scalar for String type expected?

Tags: java, deserialization, yaml, yamlbeans

## Introduction

I'm attempting to deserialize the contents of a YAML document into a Java object using [yamlbeans](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans) (v1.0).
Here's the YAML document which I'm trying to deserialize (`topologyGrammar.yml`):

```
---
rules: 
  - !tp.aoi.topology.TopologyRule { labels: ["empty_A"], output: ["entry_B"] }
```

Here's how I attempt the deserialization:

```
mainTG = (TopologyGrammar) loadYAML(TopologyGrammar.class, "grammars/topologyGrammar.yml");
```

where `loadYAML` looks like the following:

```
public Object loadYAML(Class<?> daClass, String URL) throws YamlException {
    FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal(URL);
    YamlConfig config = new YamlConfig();
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    config.readConfig.setClassLoader(classLoader);
    YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(handle.reader(), config);
    return reader.read(daClass);
}
```

This method hasn't had problems loading other YAML files I've tried.
I get the following at the top of my stack trace:

```
net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader$YamlReaderException: Line 8, column 7: Expected scalar for String type but found: sequence start
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:175)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:150)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:261)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:150)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:298)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:150)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:261)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:150)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:106)
at net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:91)
at tp.aoi.grammars.YAMLparser.loadYAML(YAMLparser.java:69)
at tp.aoi.grammars.YAMLparser.<init>(YAMLparser.java:43)
...
```

The reference to `YAMLparser.java:43` refers to the deserialization line I pasted above.

#### Class Definitions

Here's my definition for `TopologyGrammar.java`:

```
public class TopologyGrammar {
    public List<TopologyRule> rules;
}
```

And my definition for `TopologyRule.java`:

```
public class TopologyRule {
    public List<String> labels;
    public List<String> output;
}
```

## Additional Thoughts

It looks to me that the `Expected scalar for String type but found: sequence start` is referring to the `labels: ["empty_A"]` part of the document. What I'm really wondering about is why would the `YamlReader` be expecting a `String` anyway when I say that `labels` is a `List<String>` (and should therefore be represented as a sequence in the document)?

## Question

**For what reason would `YamlReader` expect a string and not a `List<String>`?**

I'm hoping that my problem isn't specific to the yamlbeans project. It seems to me that this is simply an error in how my YAML syntax relates to my class definitions.

Comment: Yes, that yaml is syntactically incorrect. Please see [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html) for YAML syntax. Also, [here's](http://pastebin.com/H4dgR4Gy) a pastebin for a sample YAML.

Comment: @SameerPuri What do you think is syntactically incorrect about the YAML? That YAML loads fine when doing a safe load.

Comment: That error doesn't correspond to the YAML source you provided. It talks about an error on line 8, where your source only has 3 lines. Please update your post with input and error that match.

Comment: The error shouldn't correspond to the YAML source, the error refers to a line in yamlbeans' YamlReader.

Comment: @karobar `Line 8, column 7` is within the YAML file

Comment: @Anthon I posted the entirety of the YAML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that YamlBeans 1.09 doesn't handle all of features in the YAML 1.2 spec, and this may have been the cause of the issue here.

I've since switched to the SnakeYaml Library and found it to a major improvement in many respects, and it deserializes the document properly.